# How to group certain element then after add item of specific criteria doing linq to sql in c#

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, windows, linq-to-sql

This might seem like a stupid question but i really need help. I don't often post question but this time i really help.

I need to have a linq to sql query that groups multiple columns. But not just that, one of the columns have specific that also need to be grouped base on `certain condition`.

The Query i have is this one.

```
using (var donnée = new ClassDonnéeDataContext(mycontrng))
        {
            var don = from d in donnée.Reservations
                      where (d.Date_Livraison.Value.Date == startDate.Value.Date) && d.Sortie_Cuisine != "Oui" && d.Livraison != "Annulée" && (d.Reserv_Boutique == "Non" || d.Reserv_Boutique == null)
                      group d by new
                      {
                          Gateau = d.Gateau,
                          Heure = d.Heure_Livraison,
                          Nb_Part = d.Part,
                      } into grs
                      select new
                      {
                          Gateau = grs.Key.Gateau,
                          Heure = grs.Key.Heure,
                          Nombre = grs.Sum(x => x.Nombre),
                          Nb_Part = grs.Key.Nb_Part,
                      };

            var order = from ord in don
                        orderby ord.Heure ascending
                        select ord;

            dgv.DataSource = order;
        }
```

The result i'm looking for is to have The columns `"Heure_Livraison"` to be grouped by specific critiria.

The result of the Query is as follow.

```
Gateau:                               Heure:                 Nombre:                  Nb_Part:

Foret Noire                           10                     2                        6
Ganache                               10                     2                        6
Foret Noire                           11                     2                        6
Ganache                               11                     2                        6
Ganache                               12                     1                        6
```

Now i want to add all the Cake of the same name, same Nb_Part `Between` `10-12.` So the result Will like

```
Gateau:                               Heure:                 Nombre:                  Nb_Part:

Foret Noire                           10                     4                        6
Ganache                               10                     5                        6
```

Please if anyone has a suggestion to this question, give it to me !!!``

Comment: Your result doesn't show grouping. How did you get `Heure` to be `10` when the source group would have `10` and `11`? What relevance is `Nb_Part` between 10-12 when all `Nb_Part` are `6`?

Comment: Thank you for your comment @NetMage, but i didn't get the Heure to be 10, that's want to get in result. Nb_Part are all 6 because they are 6 eventually so the query will show all the Nb_part to be 6. It is grouping them. I want the query to influence both Heure and Nombre.

Comment: Yes, but why with `Foret Noire` `Heure` equal to `10` and `11`, the result of grouping is `10`?

Comment: @NetMage In fact that's my expectation, what do you propose ?

Comment: I understand that is your expectation, but what logic caused `10` to be picked? Why isn't the answer in the grouped result `11`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally get to solve the problem by creating a separate column and specify the data to be stored in that column so that after when querying I just have to pick that column.

Thank you for comment !